# Color the integer output in color python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the bellow script which works fine, I only want to make `The running sum is:` integer output to be colored.

I have defined the class `style` which i am trying to use.

### Code:

```
# cat calc_running_sum.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import os    
os.system("")

# Group of Different functions for different styles
class style():
    BLACK = '\033[30m'
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    YELLOW = '\033[33m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    MAGENTA = '\033[35m'
    CYAN = '\033[36m'
    WHITE = '\033[37m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'
    
def running_sum(n):
    running_sum = 0
    for k in range(n):
        running_sum += k
    print(f'{"The running sum is: "} { running_sum }')
    # print( stlye.RED + f'{"The running sum is: "} { running_sum }')  < - this makes entire output RED

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running_sum(int(input("Enter an integer: ")))
```

### Script Output:

```
# ./calc_running_sum.py
Enter an integer: 15
The running sum is:  105
```

In the above script `105` is the output which i want to printed in red color.

Comment: `print(f'{"The running sum is: "}{style.RED}{ running_sum }{style.RESET}'`)`

Comment: I would argue that  interpolating a string literal into a string is a bit redundant. Using OP's example `print(f'The running sum is: {style.RED}{running_sum}{style.RESET}')` would work.

Comment: without `f-string` -`print("The running sum is:",  style.RED, running_sum, style.RESET)`

Comment: @Axe319 you are right - I simply copy line from question and add `RED` in correct place. But normally I would do it without `f-string` like in my next comment :)

Comment: @furas and @Axe319 , Much thanks to you guys. Is there a way to make `Enter an integer: 15` also in color.

Comment: as before you have to add codes to displayed string `input(f"{style.RED}Enter an integer:{style.RESET} ")`. It will display red text and `15` will be in normal color. But if you remove `{style.RESET}` then `15` will be also red, and all text displayed with all `print()` will be red - you would have to use `{style.RESET}` to get again text in normal color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add codes in different places in string

```
print(f'The running sum is: {style.RED}{ running_sum }{style.RESET}')
```

The same without `f-string`

```
print('The running sum is:', style.RED, running_sum, style.RESET)
```

The same with `format()`

```
print('The running sum is: {}{}{}'.format(style.RED, running_sum, style.RESET))
```

You can use different colors in the same string - ie. green text and red sum

```
print(f'{style.GREEN}The running sum is: {style.RED}{ running_sum }{style.RESET}')
```

If you don't use `{style.RESET}` then text in all next `print()` will be also red

```
print(f'The running sum is: {style.RED}{ running_sum }')
print('This text is still red')
print('And this text is also red')
```

You can use use it also in `input()`

Red text and normal value entered by user

```
input(f"{style.RED}Enter an integer:{style.RESET} ")
```

Red text and green value entered by user

```
input(f"{style.RED}Enter an integer:{style.GREEN} ")
```

But after that you may have to print `style.RESET` (without '\n') to get again normal color in next strings.

```
input(f"{style.RED}Enter an integer:{style.GREEN} ")
print(style.RESET, end="")
```

---

You can also assign color to variable to display wrong value on red and good value on green

```
if n >= 0:
    color = style.GREEN 
else:
    color = style.RED

print(f"Value: {color}{n}{style.RESET}")
#print("Value: {}{}{}".format(color, n, style.RESET))
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations and detailed answer +1 as well.